# @font-face loads duplicates in Chrome & FF

Tags: css, web, font-face

The bullet-proof @font-face syntax (both font-spring and Paul Irish flavors∞) loads duplicate files for font formats in Chrome and Firefox. I'm using both .woff and .ttf formats, and I see HTTP requests are made for both TTF and WOFF files¶.

I tinkered with the cascade and came up with a hack that seems to work. Closing off the src: property after the TTF allows browsers to break the loop.

Can someone help "check my math" and let me know if this horrible hack is a reasonable solution? Or let me know if there's another solution to preventing duplicate HTTP requests.

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"My Font";
    font-weight:normal;
    src:url('myfont.eot');
    src:url('myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        local('My Font'),
        url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    src:url('myfont.woff') format('woff');
}
```

The browser will simply apply the last relevant rule before cascading backward. I specified my preferred font last and worked backward adding the fallback formats before that. WOFF is loaded into supporting browsers while TTF is used as the fallback.

FYR:

∞ Bullet-proof syntax.
http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/
http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

¶Browsers tested: 
Chrome 17 and FF 13 on OS X, Mobile Safari in iOS 5.1.1

Comment: If this works, then it's a great temporary work-around. But a more long-term solution would be to file bug reports for Chrome and FF so the developers know this is happening.